# Level 7(HTTP) load balancing in K8S

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing

What i need: Round Robin Load balancing of HTTP requests between replicas for same service(ie: 1st request to go to Replica-1, 2nd request to go to Replica2 and so on (Modulo of replica's) irrespective of the same or different tcp connection).

What i already have:

1. Application with N replicas in K8s on AWS.(Not EKS)
2. Current trace path/setup of a request: Route53 => ALB => K8SNodePort => K8SService => Replica/Instance

Now one way to achieve this would be to add Ngnix just before replicas and do load-balancing, this doesnt seems right to me as there are 2 L7 LB's and one additional network hop. Is there any other way for this to be done efficiently?

Comment: If you don't have any particular requirements around session affinity or load-aware balancing, an ordinary Kubernetes Service should do just fine; if you need a proxy outside the cluster, it can target a NodePort Service.  What do you need beyond the defaults here?

Comment: I dont have session affinity or load-aware balancing, its purely stateless.. What i need is each request on the same or either different connection to be load balanced between N replicas.. Nothing is doing that.. unless you introduce Ngnix in the mix